# Merge two STL vectors with an alternation pattern

Tags: c++, stl, merge, vector

I have two STL vectors A and B and need to merge them into a third one, where the elements should be ordered in a way, that every nth element in the output vector should be of vector B. My current code looks something like this:

```
std::vector<int> a(10, 4);
std::vector<int> b(10, 8);
std::vector<int> c;
static const std::size_t STEP(3);

std::vector<int>::const_iterator bIt = b.begin();
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator aIt = a.begin();
    aIt != a.end(); ++aIt)
{
    c.push_back(*aIt);
    if((c.size() + 1) % STEP == 0)
    {
        c.push_back(*bIt);
        ++bIt; //assume b is large enough
    }
}
```

The vector c now looks like:
    4 4 8 4 4 8 ...

This works fine, but I'm curious if there isn't a more elegant solution. Is there any way use a STL algorithm instead of my hand-written loops?

Comment: What's with the end of c? Do you want to have it 4 4 8 .... 8 8 8 8 or just stop merging aIt is a.end() like in your example?

Comment: So, what happens if either input vector has not enough elements?

Comment: The STL already has a convention for that - what does `std::transform` do when either input sequence has not enough elements?

Comment: I've merged your accounts, you now have full control over this question. Your 'answer' however was removed, since it was directed at several people and could not be properly converted.

Answer (score 1):

This is too specialized to be covered directly by `<algorithm>`. Avoiding the loop will require a custom iterator.

```
template< typename I1, typename I2 >
struct interleave_iterator
    : std::iterator< forward_iterator_tag, typename I1::value_type > {
    using typename I1::value_type;

    I1 i1;
    I2 i2;
    size_t cnt, stride;

    interleave_iterator( I1 in1, I2 in2, size_t in_stride=0, size_t in_off=0 )
        : i1( in1 ), i2( in2 ), cnt( in_off ), stride( in_stride ) {}

    value_type &operator*() const { return cnt? * i1 : * i2; }
    interleave_iterator &operator++() {
        if ( ++ cnt == stride ) {
            cnt = 0;
            ++ i2;
        } else ++ i1;
        return *this;
    }
    value_type *operator->() const
        { return cnt? i1.operator->() : i2.operator->(); }

    interleave_iterator &operator++(int)
        { interleave_iterator r = *this; ++ *this; return r; }

    friend bool operator==
        ( interleave_iterator const &lhs, interleave_iterator const &rhs )
        { return lhs.i1 == rhs.i1 && lhs.i2 == rhs.i2; }
    friend bool operator!=
        ( interleave_iterator const &lhs, interleave_iterator const &rhs )
        { return ! ( lhs == rhs ); }
};
```

A little excessive, I think.

Comment: I think you should re-consider the ++ operator. When stride is != 1, and a and b are of equal size, it results in an exception. Is this desired behaviour?

Comment: @DyP: Eventually you will run out of space in one sequence. This class doesn't do bounds checking. I think it's totally impractical, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I quite like Potatoswatter solution... quite.

As he demonstrated, this is not an issue of algorithm, but of iteration. However his solution does not quite fit the bill because testing for the `end` of the iteration is very difficult: it requires much care in the preparation of the containers and the creation of the iterators to avoid undefined behavior.

I think the problem could be much better expressed using a concept that is quite similar to iterators: views.

A view is an Adapter interface over one or several containers. It doesn't actually contain anything itself (that's the important part). It does however exposes an interface similar to that of a container so that you can code with the usual idioms.

The beautiful things about views, is that you can often compose them.

For example, one very simple view:

```
/// Only allow to see a range of the container:
/// std::vector<int> v(40, 3); // { 3, 3, 3, ... }
/// auto rv = make_range_view(v, 4, 5);
/// rv exposes the elements in the range [4,9)
/// in debug mode, asserts that the range is sufficiently large
template <typename Container>
class range_view
{
};
```

For your question, you would rather create an `interleave_view`:

```
/// Allow to interleave elements of 2 containers each at its own pace
/// std::vector<int> v(40, 3);
/// std::set<int> s = /**/;
/// 
/// auto iv = make_interleave_view(v, 3, s, 1);
/// Takes 3 elements from v, then 1 from s, then 3 from v, etc...
template <typename C1, typename C2>
class interleave_view
{
};
```

Here the issue of the end iterator is somehow alleviated because we know both containers and thus we are able to create the iterators ourselves, ensuring we pass the proper parameters.

Of course it can become a bit more tedious if the containers do not offer an efficient "size" member (`list` doesn't, it's O(n)).

The general principle however is that a view gives you more control (and allows more checks), and is safer to use because you control precisely the creation of the iterators.

Note that in C++0x the `interleave_view` would typically accomodate an unbounded number of sequences.

Comment: The problem with adaptors is that you have to define your own interface, or try to satisfy the Container requirements. I essentially wrote an OutputIterator and called it a ForwardIterator — the notion of a sequence end is simply left open because OP didn't require it. However, that could be solved with a special `make_end_interleaved_iterator` factory, a `bool is_end` member, and a smart `operator==` which checks for set intersection among `i1` and `i2` of LHS and RHS if `is_end == true`.

Comment: Updated answer to support different semantics for range ends: the end of both underlying ranges must be attained simultaneously. So, the user must get the proportions right, but at least it's possible.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I agree that out of all the possible "views" like `filter`, `transform`, ... those who tend to have increment behave "anormally" like `skip` and `zip` offer a little challenge as to the determination of the end of a sequence.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the interface doesn't worry me too much, because it's quite terse. A view doesn't allow to modify the structure of the underlying container, so its interface is reduced. `empty`, `size`, `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `operator[]`, `at` and that's about it I think (with `const` overloads as appropriate).

Comment: Ah, now I see. That's very nice, then.